# Issue setting initial draggable position jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

I've a problem, when I set container element:

```
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
bottom: 15px;
```

And initialize draggable, bottom part of the element gets stuck to the border, and it is basically resizing rather than dragging.

http://jsfiddle.net/JVSFS/83/

So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery draggable works by modifying the `left` and `top` css properties of an object.

Set the `top` property instead of the `bottom`. 
I know it sounds like a cheap trick, but it's the fastest solution I found here.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what you told it to do. When you set `bottom` to be `10px` on an absolutely-positioned element, the bottom of that element will stay 15px from the bottom of its parent container.

It might be better in your situation to set the CSS to `position:relative` using `mousedown()` in your jQuery.

Comment: Yes that is obvious, but I thought dragable should be clearing bottom as it is doing left and top.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go about it by removing

`.popup_click {position: absolute 
left: 10px;
bottom: 15px;}`

and replacing it with: `.popup_click {top: 92%;
    left: 1%;}`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVSFS/84/)

*Please note that the percentages are just estimates based on where you had it placed before.*

Comment: This is a meh solution, same was suggested by Bobby practically. Problem with this solution is that I've to use negative margins, otherwise dragged element goes outside containment.